# Sum of two col from two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I made query:

```
SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.height_id, ad.size_id, (SUM(ad.qty)+SUM(md.qty)) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as arrival_qty, SUM(md.qty) as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id 
FROM arrival_data ad, movement_data md, arrivals a, movements m 
WHERE ad.size_id= md.size_id 
    AND ad.height_id = md.height_id 
    AND ad.spec_id = md.spec_id
    AND ad.arrival_id = a.arrival_id
    AND m.receiver = a.warehouse_id 
    AND md.movement_id = m.movement_id
GROUP BY ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id, m.receiver
```

but of course it shows results only if first and second tables have the same spec_id, size_id, height_id. I have read that join can solve this issue. Please help with right query

i solved my task by long and slow method

```
 $arrival_qty = $this->db->getOne('
            SELECT SUM(ad.qty) 
            FROM arrival_data ad, arrivals a 
            WHERE ad.arrival_id = a.arrival_id AND ad.spec_id =?i AND ad.size_id =?i AND ad.height_id =?i AND a.warehouse_id = ?i', 
            $product['spec_id'], $product['size_id'], $product['height_id'], $product['warehouse_id']);

        $move_in_qty = $this->db->getOne('
            SELECT SUM(md.qty) 
            FROM movement_data md, movements m
            WHERE md.movement_id = m.movement_id AND md.spec_id =?i AND md.size_id =?i AND md.height_id =?i AND m.receiver =?i', 
            $product['spec_id'], $product['size_id'], $product['height_id'], $product['warehouse_id']);
        $move_out_qty = $this->db->getOne('
            SELECT SUM(md.qty) 
            FROM movement_data md, movements m
            WHERE md.movement_id = m.movement_id AND md.spec_id =?i AND md.size_id =?i AND md.height_id =?i AND m.sender =?i', 
            $product['spec_id'], $product['size_id'], $product['height_id'], $product['warehouse_id']);
        $invoices_qty = $this->db->getOne('
            SELECT SUM(i.qty) 
            FROM invoice_data i, invoices m
            WHERE i.invoice_id = m.invoice_id AND i.spec_id =?i AND i.size_id =?i AND i.height_id =?i AND m.warehouse_id =?i', 
            $product['spec_id'], $product['size_id'], $product['height_id'], $product['warehouse_id']);
        $arrival_qty = (!empty($arrival_qty)) ? $arrival_qty : '0';
        $products[$key]['qty'] = $arrival_qty + $move_in_qty - $move_out_qty - $invoices_qty;
```

maybe someone can give me variant to make it by one query

Comment: What do you want the query to do?  Also, learn explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It is the proper way to write SQL queries.

Comment: i want to receive sum of two sums of rows from different tables

Answer (score 0):

[Joins Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

I don't really know, what you are trying to do. But i can find the small error, You have added a.warehouse_id in SELECT list with Aggregate function but that is not added in GROUP BY clause

So, you might get an error like this..

**Column 'a.warehouse_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

**To resolve this**, add a.warehouse_id in the GROUP BY clause or remove it from the SELECT list

Comment: SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.height_id, ad.size_id, (SUM(ad.qty)+SUM(md.qty)) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as arrival_qty, SUM(md.qty) as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id 
FROM arrival_data ad, movement_data md, arrivals a, movements m 
GROUP BY ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id, m.receiver

Comment: Use this and see, i guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Remove the unnecessary attributes to check in the where clause

Comment: why unneccessary. I need all of them

Answer (score 0):

This sort of syntax would work even if column names were different:
select sum(x) from
(
select sum(qty) as x from arrival_data
union all
select sum(qty) as x from movement_data
)
as x;

Comment: you give me variant if i need to select one field, but i need to select several other fields